# UnsupportedClassVersionError exception in Java 1.6.0

Tags: java, exception, unsupported-class-version

```
$ pwd
/home/tu/java/testpackage

$ cat Test.java 
package testpackage;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("hi");
    }
}

$ javac -version
javac 1.7.0_147

$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_23"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.11pre) (6b23~pre11-0ubuntu1.11.10.2)
OpenJDK Client VM (build 20.0-b11, mixed mode, sharing)

$ cd ..
$ javac -cp . testpackage/Test.java

$ java -cp . testpackage.Test

Exception in thread "main"
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: testpackage/Test :
Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:634)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:277)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:73)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:212)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
Could not find the main class: testpackage.Test. Program will exit.
```

What could be wrong in my case of this error?

Comment: Use `java -cp . testpackage.Test`. The argument to `java` is a **class name** and not the Java source file name.

Comment: OK, I will edit the question to reflect the progress.

Comment: I edited it, now it should reflect it. When I was trying more possibilities in the commands, this was one of the errors that occurred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`java` utility is not a compiler. It is JVM.

You should compile your code first:

`javac -cp . testpackage/Test.java`

This will produce `Test.class` file. Now you can run it:

`java -cp . testpackage.Test`

Pay attention that when you are running the program you do not have to write `.class` extension.

Comment: I have done it. Now it ends with [UnsupportedClassVersionError](http://pastebin.com/bUbiv62M)

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10585475/653379) is the continuation of the question that helped me to solve it completely.

Answer (score 0):

Remove .java from you java command.

You need to specify the *fully qualified classname* which is just "testPackage.Test".

Comment: I have done it. Now it ends with [UnsupportedClassVersionError](http://pastebin.com/bUbiv62M)

Answer (score 0):

From /home/tu/java :

java -cp . testPackage.Test

(don't put '.java' on the end)

Comment: I have done it. Now it ends with [UnsupportedClassVersionError](http://pastebin.com/bUbiv62M)