# Resolving version conflict between java and javac on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, javac, java, unsupported-class-version

I have a problem with my compiled Java application on Ubuntu. It throws `UnsupportedClassVersionError`.
I am compiling with a higher JDK version than the one that is configured in my PATH to run Java:

```
$ javac -version
javac 1.7.0_147

$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_23"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.11pre) (6b23~pre11-0ubuntu1.11.10.2)
OpenJDK Client VM (build 20.0-b11, mixed mode, sharing)
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: you may prefer to ask this question on http://askubuntu.com/ Anyways, check what java packages are installed and if the jre v1.7 is also installed you may need to configure what version to use with "alternatives"

Comment: Alternatively, try compiling with `-target 1.6` or `-source 1.6`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Run either of the following to locate where the location is of that

```
javac 1.7.0_147
```

being used as follows:

```
whereis javac
```

or

```
 locate javac
```

or

```
find javac
```

Then once you found the directory, symbolically and forcefully link the bin contents to /usr/bin:

```
sudo ln -f -s [put location here]/bin/* /usr/bin
```

Comment: I am having the same issue, but when I try this I get a new, different error: "too many levels of symbolic links"

Comment: -1, please do not attempt this answer. I think it should be unselected as the accepted answer. This will most likely cause you machine to irreversibly messed up by creating circular symlinks all over your /usr/bin directory that cannot be deleted!

Comment: @Paul This answer was directed at a person whose `javac` was *not* in `/usr/bin`. If `[put location here]/bin` turned out to be `/usr/bin` then the command becomes something completely ridiculous which you should have known - if you had tried to understand this solution instead of applying it blindly

Comment: I suppose that is true. I didn't mean to offend, and I think the answer is still useful. But maybe my public stupidity will prevent someone else from making the same mistake.

Answer (score 29):

Type following command in terminal :

```
  sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

It will ask you for:

> There are 2 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).

```
  Selection      Path                                            Priority   Status

    0           /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1061      auto mode

    1           /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1061      manual mode

    2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java  1051      manual mode


  Press enter to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:
```

I enter 2 as I want to use java 1.7.0_21

Comment: This option worked for me on Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 21):

You will also need to do:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config javac
```

Select the desired java compiler from the list provided. For example on Centos 5

```
There are 2 programs which provide 'javac'.
Selection    Command
-----------------------------------------------
1           /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk/bin/javac
*+ 2        /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk/bin/javac
```

Answer (score 3):

This is what you want [Java and Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Java). I have the same config basically, but I am switching back and forth from Glassfish and Java7. Take a look and try setting up your Java env in a  similar fashion

Answer (score 2):

I have added and installed alternatives for Java and Javac with below steps it work for me :

**Steps 1**: **Add the Java and Javac alternatives**  :

Command to add Javac:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "/opt/amazon-jdk-11/bin/java" 1
```

**i.e : "/opt/amazon-jdk-11/bin/javac" this the new path of java**

```
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javac" "javac" "/opt/amazon-jdk-11/bin/javac" 1
```

i.e : /opt/amazon-jdk-11/bin/javac is the new path of javac

**Steps 2**: **Installed the Java and Javac alternatives**  :

```
sudo update-alternatives --config javac
sudo update-alternatives --config javac
```

Once you enter above command you will able to see screen like below you can select your number that you want to configure java.

[image]

I have selected " **1** "int the list as I wanted to installed "/opt/amazon-jdk-11/bin/java" as my javac.

Verify your **Java alternative installation is successful or not with below commands** :

`which javac` and `which java`  you will able to see screen like below  :

[image]